# How relative link in href working?

Tags: url, href, relative-path, relative-url

I have a problem relating to relative links in href.  To make a long story short, I think an example is the best way to get what's going on.

On **tinhte.vn/threads/300021/**, it is a discussion forum, to go to the page 2, we click on [2].

I view source code of [2], its content is `<a href="threads/300021/page-2" class="">2</a>`. 
If I do not misunderstand about relative links, this will append `threads/30021/page-2` after the current link, which is **tinhte.vn/threads/30021/**, and we have the link like this:

> tinhte.vn/threads/300021/threads/300012/page-2

But in practice, when I do in the browser, mine is chrome, the link is:

> tinhte.vn/threads/300012/page-2

Anyone please explain why?

Sorry, due to the spam prevention, I cannot post direct link.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link will correctly go to `tinhte.vn/threads/300021/threads/300012/page-2` as you guessed. However, looking at the response from a request to that url we can see that the page *redirects* to another url. I used [web-sniffer](http://web-sniffer.net/) to quickly see the raw response from the server.

The interesting part of the response is this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="/threads/300021/page-2"/>
```

The browser will react to this and navigate to the specified URL. Hence the observed behaviour.

Read more about redirects [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection).

Comment: sorry, but i go to that link tinhte.vn/threads/300021/threads/300012/page-2, it does not redirect as you say